# Why is it "grandfather", but "great-uncle"?

Tags: word-choice, punctuation, hyphenation, word-formation, kinship-terms

I know that there are [six forms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great+-+uncle%2Cgreat+uncle%2Cgrand+-+uncle%2Cgranduncle%2Cgreatuncle%2Cgrand+uncle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of this word, but "great-uncle" is most common ("great-aunt" has a [similar graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great%20-%20aunt,great%20aunt,grand%20-%20aunt,grandaunt,greataunt,grand%20aunt&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)).  Why is this, if "grandfather" and "grandmother" are common?

[image: ngram graph]

Comment: Of course, "great uncle" and "great aunt" are ambiguous, so Ngrams might not be accurate on those terms.

Comment: "Granduncle" may not be very commonly used, but it _is_ a perfectly valid English word... and the answer to a trivia question I saw in GAMES Magazine years ago: what is the only English word to contain the sequence N-D-U-N?  From the same quiz: what is the only word to contain three consecutive pairs of letters (i.e. X-X-Y-Y-Z-Z)?

Comment: Bookkeeper! Or bookkeeping.  I have heard some people finagle a word with *four* consecutive pairs, though - subbookkeeper.

Comment: I had not heard that one - and apparently neither had the editors of GAMES back in the 80s...

Comment: @MT_Head: Presumably they hadn't encountered [undunged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undunged) either :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both *grand-* and *great-* seem to be translating the French *grand-*, as in *grand-oncle* and so on. French uses *grand-* consistently for the upward direction, and *petit-* for the reverse, as in *petit-fils* (grandson). In Latin your great-uncle is *patruus magnus* if he is on your father's side, and *avunculus magnus* on your mother's side; *magnus*, like French *grand*, can mean both "big" and "important". The root of our problem is that there are two ways to receive that into English: *grand* via Anglo-Norman *graunt*, Old French *grant*; and the Germanic *great*.

It seems that *grandsire* and *grandam* were the earliest English uses (appearing in the 13th century) which are pretty obviously based on the French. On the other hand, *great-uncle* and *grand-uncle* are both attested from the 15th century:

> his grete Uncle H. Cardinal of England (Rolls of Parliament V.438, 1438)
>
> his graunt oncle Henry cardinalle of Englande (Book of Noblesse, 1475)

These are both referring to the same person - [Cardinal Henry Beaufort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Beaufort), the great-uncle of [Henry VI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_VI_of_England).

In modern times I think most people are familiar with the "rule" that *grand-* means a difference of two generations, and repetitions of *great-* can be used for longer distances. This would suggest *grand-uncle* as the preferred form but in fact, as your chart shows, *great-uncle* is more common. Perhaps what is going on is that both words are possible English forms of *grand-oncle*, but for some reason *grand-uncle* does not feel appropriate, leaving the way clear for *great-uncle* to become standard. They are both used, and have a long history - but one is more popular. Pure speculation:

- If my grandfather is my father's father, then my grand-uncle should be my uncle's father. But that is my grandfather. So *grand-uncle* is confusing.
- *grand-* is reserved for the direct line of descent, so it feels wrong to use it for people who are off to the side

Comment: +1 for 'grand-uncle should be my uncle's father'. This is exactly why I prefer *great-uncle*.

Comment: (Oh, and lordy, did I just have a severe moment of semantic satiation with "uncle".)

Comment: In French, son-in-law/stepson is  *beau-fils*: "beautiful son", daughter-in-law/stepdaughter is *belle fille*: "beautiful daughter". Father-in-law/stepfather is *beau-père*, mother-in-law/stepmother is *belle-mère*, and *beau-frère* and *belle-sœur* for brother- and sister-in-law.

Comment: @Hugo: whereas in Hungarian, beautiful-mother and -father (szépanya, szépapa) are either great-great or great-great-great grandparents (definitions differ).

Comment: You can avoid the 'grand-uncle should be my uncle's father' mix-up by thinking of the relationship this way: My uncle is my father's brother. My grand-uncle is my grandfather's brother.

Comment: Shouldn't grand-uncle be my uncle's uncle?